# DropDownMenu React Native

Tags: react-native

i am using react-navigation and react native popup menu.

I want when I click on a button on the Navbar a menu appear with multiple choice.

I have try this :

ContactScreen.js

```
class ContactsScreen extends React.Component {
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   return {
     headerTitle: "Contacts",
     headerRight: 
     <MenuProvider>
       <Menu style={{ zIndex: 10, marginTop:20 }}>
       <MenuTrigger><Ionicons name={'ios-menu'} size={24} color={'white'} style={{marginRight: 20}} /></MenuTrigger>
       <MenuOptions style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 10, marginRight:300 }}>
           <MenuOption onSelect={() => { alert("clicked")}} text="Click me" />
       </MenuOptions>
       </Menu>
     </MenuProvider>
     ,
     headerStyle: {
       backgroundColor: theme.PRIMARY_COLOR,
     },
     headerTintColor: '#fff',
     headerTitleStyle: {
       fontWeight: 'bold',
     },
   }
 };
```

Before I click on the button :
[image: Before Click].

After I click :
[image: Atfer click]
The menu pop when i click on the icon, it overflows on the right of the screen, we do not see it entirely.

How I can resolve this ?

Comment: Is your problem still active?

Comment: yes I don't know how resolve this, or if you have another plugin , solution it could be nice

Comment: okay give me some time to run this

Comment: are you trying to create right navigation drawer?

Comment: Not I want a drop down menu ,  something like that https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5740795/34079626-58a92524-e342-11e7-816d-58f1d67ae846.png

Comment: Do you have a solution ? for react navigation

Comment: Let me see once again since you were not active so I was unable to get what you actually want.